# Passing a php variable to javascript inside php function that echos js code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm coding a plug-in for WP and I'm writing a `JavaScript` script to the `head` of the page document using php's `echo`. I need to pass some `php` variables to the script. I tried `json.encode()` but it does not pass the right thing here is my function:

```
function test_action()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $contents = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT content FROM wp_map_user_demo");
    $lats = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT latitude FROM wp_map_user_demo");
    $longs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT longitude FROM wp_map_user_demo");

    //Modifying the header file of WP
    echo '<title>Demo</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>';
    //Including the custom Google Maps script
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    var map;
                    var contents = ". json_encode($contents) .";
                    var lats = ". json_encode($lats) . ";
                    var longs = " .  json_encode($longs). ";

                    document.write('<p>' + lats[0] + '</p>');
                    function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[0], longs[0]),
                      zoom: 8
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                        mapOptions);
                  }
                  //map.setOptions({draggable: true});
                  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>";
}
```

When I open the page on WP `document.write('<p>' + lats[0] + '</p>');` outputs `[object Object]` on the page instead of latitude data.I checked the php variables and they are correct, so I guess that my problem is with `JavaScript` usage.

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: Try this: `document.write('<p>' + json_stringify(lats) + '</p>');` as your variable is json encoded and let us know what is output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
function test_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT content,latitude,longitude FROM wp_map_user_demo");

    $contents = $lats = $longs = array();

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $contents[] = $result->content;
        $lats[] = $result->latitude;
        $longs[] = $result->longitude;
    }

    //Modifying the header file of WP
    echo '<title>Demo</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey"></script>';
    //Including the custom Google Maps script
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    var map;
                    var contents = " . json_encode($contents) . ";
                    var lats = " . json_encode($lats) . ";
                    var longs = " . json_encode($longs) . ";

                    document.write('<p>' + lats[0] + '</p>');
                    function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lats[0], longs[0]),
                      zoom: 8
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                        mapOptions);
                  }
                  //map.setOptions({draggable: true});
                  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript variable `lats` is an array of objects, so when you do `lats[0]` you're getting the first object in the array. To get the latitude value you need to access the `latitude` property of the object:

```
document.write('<p>' + lats[0].latitude + '</p>');
```

It's the same for your longitude:

```
longs[0].longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `$wpdb->get_results` doesn't return a `String` but an `Result Set` Object. You should try `$wpdb->get_var` if you want to access it directly instead.

Edit: Or access the properties of the `Result Set` like MrCode said.